# how to return service function data to component using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a service with s3 bucket upload functionality and i am able to upload images into s3. but i am unable to return information from service layer to component.

Could you please help me on this?

**Service.ts:**

```
async uploadFile(file, path): Promise<any> {
    const contentType = file.type;
    const bucket = new S3(
      {
        accessKeyId: 'My Access Key',
        secretAccessKey: 'My Secret Key',
        region: 'eu-west-1'
      }
    );
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'sangram-adaptive',
      Key: path + '/' + file.name,
      Body: file
    };
    
    await bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
        return err;
      }

      if (data) {
        console.log('Successfully uploaded', data); // i am getting result after upload
        this.fileData = data;
        return this.fileData; 
      }
    });
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
async upload() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    let data = await this.s3FileuploadService.uploadFile(file, 'tenant_files/' + Constants.TENANT + '/blogs');
    console.log(data); // Here it's showing undefined
  }
```

[image]

Comment: your are not awating `bucket.upload` and uploadFile is not an async function

Comment: @RafiHenig updated my question. i am using await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider modifying  `uploadFile` to return Promise as below:

```js
uploadFile(file, path): Promise<any> {
  const contentType = file.type;
  const bucket = new S3(
    {
      accessKeyId: 'My Access Key',
      secretAccessKey: 'My Secret Key',
      region: 'eu-west-1'
    }
  );
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'sangram-adaptive',
    Key: path + '/' + file.name,
    Body: file
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data))    
  })
}
```

Comment: `Fbucket` where can i get ?

Comment: `bucket.upload` is not returning promise, but taking a callback instead, therefore my solution is to warp it with Promise object...

Answer (score 0):

Which type does the function `bucket.upload` return?

Shouldn't you maybe call it with:

```
await bucket.upload(...)
```

In case it returns a promise?